# Open running KVM in separate session

Tags: kvm, session

I have a KVM session running on my host.  If I login as someone else on my host machine, is it possible to access that running KVM session (not through the network)?

I am not using the virtual manager either - I started the machine with the `kvm` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing more research, I discovered I was executing the VM wrong.  The proper way to do so would be to use the [virsh utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/virsh).  After starting a vm that way (with `start vm-name`), you can use the [virt-viewer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/virt-viewer) to view the running VM.

Answer (score 2):

The method of accessing the console of a VM you started manually with the `kvm` command would depend on which arguments you used.  By default, KVM will try to use SDL to display the VGA output.  This limits output to only the current logged in user (X session, basically).

A better way to do it is to add `-vnc :0` to your arguments.  This will tell KVM to redirect the VGA display over a VNC session on the standard VNC port of 5900 (for other ports, see below).  You can then access the console with any VNC viewer; tell it to use hostname `localhost` and port `5900`.

To use a different VNC port, just do `-vnc :1` for port 5901, `-vnc :2` for port 5902, and so on...

`virsh` does all this for you behind the scenes.  In fact `virt-viewer` is simply a minimal VNC client.

Answer (score 0):

You can access vm by use spice, vnc or rdp etc..
All access methods need to assign a port. You can use 127.0.0.1:port to access the vm. This will not use the network for real.